# Trouble Assigning Public IP to GCP Compute Instance with CDKTF in Python

Tags: python, google-cloud-platform, terraform, terraform-provider-gcp, terraform-cdk

I am currently exploring CDKTF (Terraform's Cloud Development Kit) with Python to manage GCP resources, specifically to create a GCP compute instance with a public IP address. While I've successfully done this using HCL in Terraform, I'm encountering challenges in achieving the same with CDKTF (converted from HCL using `cdktf convert`).

Here's my CDKTF Python code:

```py
from cdktf import Fn, Token, TerraformOutput, TerraformStack, App

from cdktf_cdktf_provider_google.provider import GoogleProvider
from cdktf_cdktf_provider_google.compute_instance import ComputeInstance
from cdktf_cdktf_provider_google.compute_firewall import ComputeFirewall
from cdktf_cdktf_provider_google.compute_address import ComputeAddress

class MyConvertedCode(TerraformStack):
    def __init__(self, scope, name):
        super().__init__(scope, name)

        GoogleProvider(
            self, "google", project="example-project", region="us-west1"
        )

        google_compute_instance_example_instance = ComputeInstance(
            self,
            "example_instance",
            boot_disk={"initialize_params": {"image": "debian-cloud/debian-11"}},
            machine_type="f1-micro",
            name="example-instance--via-cdktf",
            network_interface=[
                {
                    "network": "default",
                    "access_config":[{}],
                }
            ],
            zone="us-west1-a",
        )

        TerraformOutput(
            self,
            "instance_network_interface",
            value=google_compute_instance_example_instance.network_interface,
        )
```

Here's the console output (notice the empty `access_config`):

```bash
  instance_network_interface = [
    {
      "access_config": [],
      "alias_ip_range": [],
      "internal_ipv6_prefix_length": 0,
      "ipv6_access_config": [],
      "ipv6_access_type": "",
      "ipv6_address": "",
      "name": "nic0",
      "network": "https://www.googleapis.com/compute/v1/projects/example-project/global/networks/default",
      "network_ip": "10.111.2.33",
      "nic_type": "",
      "queue_count": 0,
      "stack_type": "IPV4_ONLY",
      "subnetwork": "https://www.googleapis.com/compute/v1/projects/example-project/regions/us-west1/subnetworks/default",
      "subnetwork_project": "example-project"
    }
  ]
```

### Expectations

- I expect a non-empty `access_config` containing the public IP or `nat_ip`.

### Questions

1. Why does the CDKTF approach not automatically assign a public IP when `access_config` is left empty, unlike the HCL Terraform script?
2. Is there a specific configuration or approach I am missing in CDKTF to ensure the GCP compute instance gets a public IP?

Any insights or suggestions would be greatly appreciated. I am open to alternative approaches or corrections in my current implementation.

---

### Appendix

##### Environment and Versions

- Terraform version: `v1.5.7`
- Python version: `3.12.1`
- CDKTF version: `0.19.2`
- CDKTF provider versions (from Poetry's `pyproject.toml`):

  ```bash
  [tool.poetry.dependencies]
  python = "^3.9"
  cdktf-cdktf-provider-google = "^12.1.0"
  ```

Comment: You are including a lot of detail that is not helpful and making it very hard to figure out what is what. Describe the problem first with code/errors/expectations. It is OK to then show what you tried, but a subject matter expert does not need your efforts or want to understand the puzzle you created or need the equivalent HCL. Show the code (all of it and not using `...`) that you are using, and the error/results. Follow this [guide](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: Noted. Thank you for your guidance @JohnHanley. I simplified the question and hope it's improved.

Comment: Aren't you passing empty `access_config` along with `network_interface`?

Comment: You must specify the `access_config`. Do you want Google Cloud to assign a public IP address or use a reserved IP address?